# how to increse upload file size into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload1/".$name);
$url="video/upload/$name";

mysql_query("insert into video (name,url) values('$name','$url')");
```

Comment: `mysql` does not store the images, it stores the path... Search for _["Upload large files in "](https://www.google.co.in/?ion=1&espv=2#q=upload%20large%20files%20in%20php)_

Comment: You have to change in your php.ini file not in mysql file.

Comment: there is no size problem with this code unless you have a very long $name or $url

Comment: Required reading: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Also, for everyone's sake, stop using whatever resource gave you that code. It's 2016, not the turn of the century...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you modified  php.ini.

**post_max_size = 25M**

> Just change your php.ini(xampp/php/php.ini) file, it worked for me.

```
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
```

And, don't forget to restart MySQL Module from XAMPP Control Panel

Comment: I see no evidence XAMPP is involved here.

Comment: how did you know it was wrong php.ini or that he was using xampp?